# Reference request - Online copy of T. N. Sinha's "Note on perfect numbers"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) likely needs no introduction.

**Reference Request**

I was wondering if there is an online copy of the following journal article:

> T. N. Sinha, Note on perfect numbers, *Math. Student* **42** (1974), 336.

I tried a quick Google search, but was unable to find any helpful search results.

I also tried accessing the journal's website via http://www.indianmathsociety.org.in/ms.htm, but the publication year in question is missing from the list of the *scanned copies* of the contents pages of the very old Math. Student issues.

Lastly, I tried searching [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=Sinha+perfect+number&sort=&language=english&go=Search), still to no avail.

**Context**

I learned about Sinha's paper via Tomohiro Yamada's preprint [On Sinha's note on perfect numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.12184v2).

Comment: Have you tried asking Yamada?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @RicardoBuring!  I will go ahead and e-mail Professor Yamada.  =)

Comment: I have already e-mailed Professor Yamada.  I will post an update here ASAP.

Comment: I thought I would add that I checked through all avenues available to me (which I think are quite extensive through my work and university), and I do not have access to a digital version. And due to various lockdowns, I cannot access my university's physical copy. However if you cannot find a copy, it is possible for me to ask other universities who are running library services to scan and send me a copy.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful gesture, @davidlowryduda!  Please let me know how it goes.  I have been away from university for a number of years and I am afraid that I do not have the same academic connections like you do.  =(

Comment: Good day, @davidlowryduda!  Professor Yamada did not reply to my e-mail, requesting for a copy of Sinha's paper.  =(

Comment: I have asked another library to scan and send me a copy. I am told they batch these requests right now and will get back to me in some amount of time. When I hear back, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you for this, @davidlowryduda!  This is much appreciated.  =)

Comment: Ok, it took a bit, but I now have this. You can find it [here](https://davidlowryduda.com/static/math/NoteOnPerfectNumbers.pdf). Note that this is just some link in static files in my site, and I don't intend to keep it there permanently. (But I'll probably forget about it, so it might sit there for a really long time until I clean out cruft)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @davidlowryduda!  I got the file already.  =)